# Simple Android searchbar into a string

Tags: java, android, sdk

***MY GOAL***:take whatever was placed into the search bar and then turn it into a string which can be a variable used across multiple activities. I am wondering on line 92 , would i need a if statement of some sort to see if there are any integers passed. That then would need to be converted into a string. Or Would the code work fine the way it is. Thank you for reading!

```html
package com.karanvir.search;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent intentGoogle;
    Random rn;
    SharedPreferences urls;
    AutoCompleteTextView searchBar;
    public static String urlGlobal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        searchBar=(AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
        Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        Intent intentGoogle= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
         rn= new Random();

        urls=this.getSharedPreferences("com.karanvir.search", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);






    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings4) {
            startActivity(intentGoogle);

            return true;
        } else if(id ==R.id.action_settings2){


            return true;

        }else if (id==R.id.action_settings3){


            return true;

        }else if(id==R.id.action_settings1){
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.alert_dark_frame)
                    .setTitle("About")
                    .setMessage("stuff");
                    return true;

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void jump(View view){
        //intnet changing target of our code
urlGlobal=searchBar.getText().toString();
        if


        //public static String urlGlobal=




       /* urls.edit().putString("url",searchBar.getText().toString()).apply();
        String Stringurls=urls.getString("url","");*/

        int pageJump = rn.nextInt(3)+1;
        if (pageJump==1){
            startActivity(intentGoogle);
        } else if (pageJump==2){

        } else if(pageJump==3){

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it does convert it into a string so there is no need for further complications.